# Why are there so many incestuously suggestive anime?

Tags: anime-production, tropes, law

There are many anime that have incestuous theme. For example, *OniAi*, *Eromanga Sensei*, *Kiss X Sis*, *Ore no Imouto ga Konnani Kawaii Wake ga Nai*, *Yosuga no Sora*, *Saikin, Imouto no Yousu ga Chotto Okashiinda ga* and so on.

Why are there so many incestuously suggestive anime? Some of them were even aired on TV, which probably could spoil public morals. Wouldn't people, especially parents, protest?

Comment: In Japan, they are midnight anime for mature audiences though, not for children or teens.

Comment: @AkiTanaka But a child can find them on the Internet freely.

Comment: Also related, an article by Answerman in 2017: [Why Is Incest Such A Common Topic In Anime?](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/answerman/2017-03-01/.112826)

Comment: Does this [INCLUDE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/91992/can-step-siblings-marry-in-catholicism) step-siblings? or [EXCLUDE](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67040/why-when-being-romantically-affectionate-do-these-ex-romantic-partner-step-sibli)?

Comment: @BCLC That depends on their relation before they become family. Step-siblings like those in *Domestic na Kanojo* are fine, because at least they are in relationship before they become family, and therefore the incest is due to bad luck, while the one in *Eromanga Sensei* is kinda immoral.

Comment: [This article](http://psychohistory.com/articles/the-universality-of-incest/) may give some insights into the incest thing in Japan.

Comment: *OreImo* isn't merely "incestuously suggestive", it's just incestuous, period.

Comment: @Michael immoral is subjective. It's either legal or it isn't. Personally I find all step-sibling relationships weird and consequently I find all co-parent-in-law marriage weird but eh it's either that or we run into this [who-came-1st problem](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/41600/can-co-parents-in-law-marry-for-example-a-husbands-father-and-a-wifes-mother). What's illegal about the Eromanga Sensei thing? (Heard of it but haven't seen.)

Comment: There aren't really that many. You'll have a tough time counting to a mere 30, let alone 100. It's the same for tentacle anime. Maybe people just feel that a couple are already too many?

Comment: @Ocean i was told the opposite. i myself can't think ANY actually but people tell me like in kaguya-sama 'oh wow miyuki and kei shirogane are the most realistic opposite gender siblings i've seen in anime. so many others are incestuous.' but i haven't really seen any like all sibling relationships in and out of anime are realistic to me.

Comment: @BCLC it's probably more of a meme than it is reality. Try pressing someone making such claims for an actual list and see how many titles they can get.

Comment: @Ocean Well according to them...what do you say to No Game No Life, Mahouka, Sword Art Online, Code Geass, Attack on Titan?

Comment: @BCLC sounds like they are grasping at straws, but even if you count those you still have a hard time to count to 100. For perspective, there are about 14.000 anime in existence.

Comment: @Ocean THANK YOU. GOD BLESS YOU. There is another matter though. A lot of anime main/major characters are only children. I tried to think of a lot of anime examples that 1ST have relevant sibling characters AND THEN to see if they are incestuous or something. Of the 14k anime, how many do you estimate have relevant sibling characters? If it's like only 1k, then 100/1k = 10% I think is already a noticeable minority.

Comment: @BCLC Among those 14K about 1K are pornographic in nature and the number of anime with relevant sibling characters is a lot less. I mentioned grasping at straws because as soon as you count stuff like Code Geass you are essentially counting all anime with mixed sex siblings, but even if you do you'll have a hard time counting to 100. Though, if you reduce it purely to siblings existing you might make it past 100. It's still going to be tough and I'd be surprised if you can make it to 200. Unless you count siblings where neither is the protagonist.

Comment: @BCLC for a bit more context on the anime porn number; there are about 1000 hentai, maybe even close to 1500. For that to happen they had to make about 40 hentai every year since 1980. (There arguably weren't either hentai or otaku anime before 1980.)